# get status of users from contactlist

Tags: xmpp

I need get status of users from  contactlist.
I use openfire server.
On  server i send following  xml

```
<iq type="get" from="dezhavi@domen.com" id="3"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/></iq>
```

And get from server

```
<iq type="result" id="3" to="dezhavi@domen.com/webi"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="user1@im.onmetapoint.com" name="user1" subscription="both"><group>Friends</group></item></query></iq>
```

But no status.

How get user status?

Comment: Did you read http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6121#section-4 ?

Answer (score 2):

To get the Status you should use a presence Stanza.

The trust or access decision behind presence happens naturally in IM systems, because
people you approve are automatically added to your contact list (called a roster in
XMPP), which is typically the *“home base”* for any instant messaging or real-time
communications application.

In addition, presence access is usually bidirectional: you allow a contact to see your
presence, and your contact allows you to see his presence. This happens through a
subscription “handshake”. If the handshake is completed successfully,
the result is a bidirectional presence subscription between the two parties.
(XMPP servers also add the contact to the user’s roster and add the user to the contact’s
roster during this process, plus manage a state machine of subscription states, refer to [RFC 3921] for a full description.)

Let’s see how the subscription handshake works in practice.
**To request someone’s presence, you send him a subscription request, which is a
 stanza of type subscribe:**

```
<presence from="alice@wonderland.lit" to="sister@realworld.lit" type="subscribe"/>
```

When the intended recipient receives your presence subscription request, he can either
approve it (via a  stanza of type subscribed) or deny it (via a 
stanza of type unsubscribed):

```
<presence from="sister@realworld.lit" to="alice@wonderland.lit" type="subscribed"/>
```

As you might imagine, to create a bidirectional presence subscription, the person who
approved the original subscription request needs to send a subscription request of his
own:

```
<presence from="sister@realworld.lit" to="alice@wonderland.lit" type="subscribe"/>
```

Typically, your client will auto-reply at this point, rather than asking you to manually
approve the reverse request:

```
<presence from="alice@wonderland.lit" to="sister@realworld.lit" type="subscribed"/>
```

Once you are subscribed to another person’s presence, you will automatically be notified
when the other party’s network or communications availability changes. This
presence notification takes the form of a  ***stanza*** with no type attribute (i.e., implicitly indicating availability):

```
<presence from="alice@wonderland.lit/rabbithole" to="sister@realworld.lit">
   <show>xa</show>
   <status>down the rabbit hole!</status>
</presence>
```